# how to access the field with name?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**hello guys. why i cloud to access . when i want to access the file id like blow:**

```
echo $row['id'];
```

i have to do this blow:

```
echo $row[0];
```

{the number of the field} ?? 
some times it ok ??

**i use this code for get data from DB :**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=".$number."");
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);  
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Tnx  Charlotte Dunois. second comment is helpfull

Comment: help me about your first comment

Comment: Open the link, the help is in there.

Comment: how can i use  WHERE id=?  in above  in your linke for sql injection ??

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem long time ago.

you must use "mysqli_fetch_array($result)" 
instead of using "mysqli_fetch_row($result)"